# Uniform convergence of specific sequence on a compact subset of the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

I would like to show the uniform convergence of two sequences $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ to $f : z \mapsto \frac{2z}{z^2 - \pi^2}$ and to $g: z \mapsto z$ on any compact K of the complex plane where the functions are defined. Here
$$
f_n(z)
=\frac{2n \tan \frac{z}{n}}{(\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{n})(n \tan \frac{z}{n})^2 -(n \sin \frac{\pi}{n} )^2}
$$
and
$$
g_n(z)=n\tan \frac{z}{n}.
$$
I can show the simple convergence but I does not know the methods for uniform convergence on compact subsets of the complex plane.

Comment: It is not just true for compact $K$, but for any bounded set. All you need is that there is some $R$ such that $|z| < R$ on $K$.